# What is the difference between the * operator at the end of struct name vs in front of struct name?

Tags: c, pointers

I am following a C tutorial for a Linked List and I am building the node. However, I do not understand why the * operator comes at the end of the node variable versus in front of it. I thought pointers came in front of the word. So which is the pointer? "next" or "node"?

```
struct node {
    int value;
    // next pointer, should point to the next node in the list
    struct node* next; // pointer of structure type
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct node` is the type so it comes in front of that, like `int* num`, only in this case type `int` is only one word.

Another hint to this is that variable names can only have one word.

So `struct node*` (pointer to struct node) is the type, and `next` is the name of the variable.

[See here](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+node*+next)